# Как исправить Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed?

Tags: python, heroku

Когда пытаюсь запушить на heroku то выдает такую ошибку:

```
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
remote:            This backport is for Python 2.7 only.
remote:            
remote:            ----------------------------------------
remote:        Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-7w4exzcs/functools32/
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Либо перенести код на Python 3, либо создать окружение на втором питоне.
Вы же видите:

```
This backport is for Python 2.7 only
```

На heroku в файле runtime.txt указывается версия питона, насколько мне известно.